# How do I solve this differential equation that are related?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Suppose I have these $2$ equations:

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = -y + 3x$$
$$\frac{dx}{dt} = 4x - 2y.$$

Then I want to show that I can reduce them into a single ODE in $2$nd order expressed for $y(t)$. What I have done is that I found these by differentiating:

$$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2} = 5y - 9x$$
$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = 10x -6y$$

and dividing these two equations together, I can get $y''(x)$ but not in $y(t)$ form. I tried to integrate from the very first ODE, but it gives me further algebraic expressions that I don't think is helpful.

Any hints will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think dividing the last two equations actually gives you what you think it does.

Comment: Call $z=\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}$ and $A=\begin{pmatrix}4&-2\\3&-1\end{pmatrix}$. Then the system is $z'=Az$. It follows that $z=Ce^{tA}$

Answer (score 1):

According to the first equation, $3x= y+y'$, and deriving, $3x' = y' + y''$. Substitute both in the second equation and you will have a second order ODE in $y$.

Answer (score 0):

from the second equation we get
$$y=-\frac{1}{2}x'+2x$$ so we have
$$y'=\frac{1}{2}x'+2x+3x$$ and we get $$y'=-\frac{1}{2}x''+2x'$$ and we get
$$-\frac{1}{2}x''+2x'=\frac{1}{2}x'-2x+3x$$
can you solve this?

Comment: In the second line, is it supposed to be $+3x$ instead? On the third line, should it be $y''$? If so, the equality in the last line might not match, I think.

Comment: ok i have lost a $x$, i will check it

Comment: this was just a typo, but thanks for the $-1$

Comment: Just some clarification: I did not $-1$ you...I have upvoted you now (your score should be high enough to see how many upvotes and down votes). Also check my profile I have not casted any downvotes before...

Comment: thank you for your statement! i wish you a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be better method for getting $y''(t)$:
We rewrite the above system of equation into this form 
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
3x-(D+1)y=0\\
(D-4)x+2y=0 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~where~~~ D\equiv \dfrac {d}{dt}.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Then multiply first equation by $(D-4)$ and second equation by $3$ and subtracting we get $(D^2-3D+2)y=0$ which is equivalent to

> $y''(t)-3y'(t)+2y(t)=0.$

Also from this ODE you can directly find $y(t)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}4&-2\\3&-1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}
$$
Using the Jordan Decomposition, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\exp\left(t\begin{bmatrix}4&-2\\3&-1\end{bmatrix}\right)
&=\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\3&1\end{bmatrix}
\exp\left(t\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}\right)
\begin{bmatrix}-1&1\\3&-2\end{bmatrix}\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\3&1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}e^t&0\\0&e^{2t}\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}-1&1\\3&-2\end{bmatrix}\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\3&1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}-e^t&e^t\\3e^{2t}&-2e^{2t}\end{bmatrix}\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}3e^{2t}-2e^t&2e^t-2e^{2t}\\3e^{2t}-3e^t&3e^t-2e^{2t}\end{bmatrix}\\
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}3e^{2t}-2e^t&2e^t-2e^{2t}\\3e^{2t}-3e^t&3e^t-2e^{2t}\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}x_0\\y_0\end{bmatrix}
$$